# Extract pixels from canvas-Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm currently working on a project, for which I need to work with the pixels of a canvas. I do extract the pixels by using canvascontext.getImageData(0,0,width,height).data(). This piece of code works well and returns an array of pixels. Inside this array the pixels are positioned like that: [r1,g1,b1,a1,r2,g2,b2,a2...]. Now I've worked with a similar array in Java, but here the pixels where returned like that: [r1,r2,g1,g2,b1,b2,a1,a2] which made it possible to use a mask to get the values.
Since it is different in JS I used the following functions to extract the values from the array and set them after editing:

```
 ImageClass.prototype.getRed = function(temp){
   return imageData.pixels[temp];
 }

 ImageClass.prototype.setRed = function(r, temp){
   imageData.pixels[temp] = r;
 }

 ImageClass.prototype.getGreen = function(temp){
   return imageData.pixels[Number(temp)+1];
 }

 ImageClass.prototype.setGreen = function(g, temp){
   imageData.pixels[Number(temp)+1] = g;
 }

 ImageClass.prototype.getBlue = function(temp){
   return imageData.pixels[Number(temp)+2];
 }

 ImageClass.prototype.setBlue = function(b, temp){
   imageData.pixels[Number(temp)+2] = b;
 }

 ImageClass.prototype.getAlpha = function(temp){
   return imageData.pixels[Number(temp)+3];
 }

 ImageClass.prototype.setAlpha = function(a, temp){
   imageData.pixels[Number(temp)+3] = a;
 }
```

temp is a integer-value which represents an index. Now my question: While the following function (red) works, the next one(green) does not work. I have not an idea why and how to start debugging.

```
ImageClass.prototype.red = function(){
  this.getPixels();
  for (index = 0; index < imageData.pixelsLength; index += 4) {
    var g = this.getGreen(index);
    var b = this.getBlue(index);

    g = 0;
    b = 0;

    this.setGreen(g, index);
    this.setBlue(b, index);

  }
  this.draw();
}

ImageClass.prototype.green = function(){
  this.getPixels();
  for (index = 0; index < imageData.pixelsLength; index += 4) {
    var r = this.getRed(index);
    var b = this.getBlue(index);

    r = 0;
    b = 0;

    this.setRed(r, index);
    this.setBlue(b, index); 
  }
  this.draw();
}
```

The getPixels()-function just makes the pixels-array globally available (in a namespace). The draw-function does excactly what the name says it does.

If anybody knows an easier way to extract the pixels from the array, so that I can access all the reds, all the greens, etc. I'm open for suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the calls to getGreen and getBlue, since you're just overriding them anyway.

### Slight Modification

```
ImageClass.prototype.red = function(){
  this.getPixels();
  for (index = 0; index < imageData.pixelsLength; index += 4) {
    var g = 0, b = 0;

    this.setGreen(g, index);
    this.setBlue(b, index);

  }
  this.draw();
}
```

### Avoid `ImageClass.prototype.getRed`, etc.

If you want a very simple method, you can do this:

```
offsets {r: 0, g: 1, b: 2, a: 3}

ImageClass.prototype.red = function(){
  this.getPixels();
  for (index = 0; index < imageData.pixelsLength; index += 4) {
      imageData.pixels[index+offsets.g] = 0;
      imageData.pixels[index+offsets.b] = 0;
  }
  this.draw();
}
```

### Simple and Complete Alternative

You can avoid duplicate code by generating these functions.

```
offsets {r: 0, g: 1, b: 2, a: 3}

function MakeColorFunction(omit1, omit2){
  return (function(){
    this.getPixels();
    for (index = 0; index < imageData.pixelsLength; index += 4) {
      imageData.pixels[index+offsets[omit1]] = 0;
      imageData.pixels[index+offsets[omit2]] = 0;
    }
    this.draw();
  });
}

ImageClass.prototype.red = MakeColorFunction("g", "b");
ImageClass.prototype.green = MakeColorFunction("b", "r");
ImageClass.prototype.blue = MakeColorFunction("r", "g");
```

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of `imageData.pixels[index+offsets.g];` in your second code-block? It looks like a no-operation statement to me.. Did you mean to get some data from there?

Comment: @enhzflep, typo.  I meant to set it to 0.

Comment: Beauty! Thought so. :grin:

Comment: The very first version of the last piece of code confused me. But this one I like. It does look better than mine I have to admit, but one last question though. Why should I Avoid ImageClass.prototype.getRed, etc. ?

Comment: If you don't need them for anything else, it makes your code shorter.  For this imageClass.red, etc., not using them makes it (much) faster.